# How to show category images (from plugin) on a regular page (page-example.php)?

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, images, pages

I am trying to use the [Category Images Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/) to show images with my Custom Taxonomy (Region) categories/terms. Here is the code I have so far in a page-example.php that lists all the categories/terms with their descriptions:

```
$siteurl = home_url('/');
$tax = 'region';  // slug of taxonomy

$terms = get_terms($tax);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $slug = $term->slug;
    $description = $term->description;
    $link = "<a href='$siteurl?$tax=$slug' ><h1> $term->name </h1></a>";

    echo $link;
    echo '<p>' . $description . '</p>';
}
```

The documentation for the [Category Images Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/) says "Use [the function] to get the url and put it in any img tag in ***category or taxonomy*** template.

Is it possible to get the image urls in my existing code even though it's a regular page and not a category or taxonomy template file?

Any help or direction would be much appreciated as I'm not sure where to even start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but something like this should work.

```
$siteurl = home_url('/');
$tax = 'region';  // slug of taxonomy
$terms = get_terms($tax);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $id = $term->term_id;
    $slug = $term->slug;
    $description = $term->description;
    $image_url = z_taxonomy_image_url( $id, NULL, TRUE );
    $link = "<a href='$siteurl?$tax=$slug' ><h1> $term->name </h1></a>";

    echo $link;
    echo '<p>' . $description . '</p>';
    echo '<img src="' . $image_url . '">';
}
```

2nd argument of `z_taxonomy_image_url()` is image size and 3rd argument is for returning placeholder image.

Comment: Thanks. It's working...sort of :) It's only loading the placeholder image for all of the categories. I changed "NULL" to "thumbnail", "medium", "large" but no change. Any ideas?

Comment: Just tested and it works for me. Are you sure you've uploaded images to your terms?

Comment: Very sorry, I did not see that you had added `$id = $term->term_id;`. After seeing your answer I only added the `$image_url` lines. Copying and pasting the whole chunk of code works! Thank you for your time and answer.